# How to back up non-standard directories in my user profile with Windows Backup?

Tags: windows-7, windows, backup, windows-backup

I'm using Windows Backup to back up my Win7 Pro laptop.  I'd like to use it to back up my complete user profile, but I only see standard profile directories (e.g. C:\Users\JohnstonJ\Documents) in the list.  Non-standard ones aren't there (e.g. C:\Users\JohnstonJ\MyCustomDirectory).

What's the best way to handle this?  The only thing I can think of is to browse under the "Computer" entry and navigate directly to C:\Users\JohnstonJ and check off the entire profile (to get what's in there, and any new directories that come up).  But is that going to back up the profile twice?  Cause other unforeseen problems given that I checked it off by navigating through the computer, rather than picking it under the "Data Files" category?  (e.g. back up temporary file garbage, files in use problems, etc. that the "Data Files" category might be handling better).

Looking for solutions that other people use that are known to work well and still uses the Windows Backup software - I don't really want to fuss with 3rd-party backup software.

Example - as you can see, I have two directories in my profile that Windows Backup is not offering to back up: "Dropbox" and "New folder":

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since you are using the libraries to manage your data:
What about creating a new library with those two folders manually? You should be able to select the folders in the way you want then.

Answer (score 6):

As you've already realized yourself, referencing the files through the *My Computer* branch may not be desirable because it may treat the folder like a *normal* folder and not a profile folder.

The thing is, the folders that are not listed **are not part of your profile**. They just happen to be stored in the same location.

The folders that you can select for backup *inside* your profile all have special meaning to Windows. Your `Dropbox` folder doesn't mean anything to Windows. It's just another plain old folder.

Which is why you would want to select the folder through the plain old *My Computer* branch in the backup wizard ;)

#### Problems

So, one question remains, will this pose a problem for your backup?
Possibly. But I doubt it's for the reason you assume

I'm almost certain all selected locations are backed up in identical ways. The major difference will be how the data will be **restored**.

For example, your `My Pictures` folder, will **always** be restored into your `My Pictures` folder. No matter where on your system it is located. You could have moved it to `Y:\Something\Users\James\My Pictures` and your pictures would end up there.

Your folder `C:\Users\James\Dropbox\`... it will **always** be restored to `C:\Users\James\Dropbox\`.

I'm sure the distinction goes a bit deeper than fixed paths. But I'm sure the biggest part in the distinction is how the data is *labeled* for later restore.

Comment: Generally I'd say the user profile *is* the folder where everything else resides, i.e. `\Users\Foo` by default. This is also (excepting the local application data) the definition that is used with user profiles in domains. Saying that your profile only encompasses data under a few special folders is a bit misleading in my eyes.

Comment: @Joey: I don't agree. But I might be misinformed. Maybe it's just an issue with the terminology I'm using. Feel free to improve my answer, maybe I will agree with you after I read it :)

Comment: @Joey: I didn't realize you were the one who bountied the question. Let me elaborate on my position regarding the *profile* term. I always considered only those parts in the `Users` folder to be *profile data*, which is referenced as such by the system (like the contents of the `AppData` folder). A file that is placed in that folder is somewhat orphaned and not part of the profile. Or to put it differently yet again, `C:\Users\Oliver\` is the storage location of my profile, but it doesn't represent my profile. I wrote the answer to the best of my knowledge and wouldn't know how to improve it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use DataGrab to backup your entire profile, including all the folders/settings in oyur user profile.

[image]

You can download it [here.](https://sites.google.com/a/obxcompguy.com/foolish-it/vb6-projects/datagrab)

Comment: The original question does explicitly state that he'd prefer not to use third person tools though

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Missed that, yet I will keep this answer.

Comment: +1 because of that tool. But it is not the actual answer though :)

Comment: The tool is written in VB6, so it will likely not be able to handle Unicode file names at all. Which is a major drawback for people using that (and *I* certainly don't want my backup mangled).